# How to read the output of the R package checking with valgrind

Tags: r, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am preparing a R package, indeed it is on github (https://github.com/whcsu/JMcmprsk). I have pass the R CMD check-as -cran on windows and linux

But it cannot pass CRAN's valgrind test:

Here is the output after running

```
R -d valgrind
```

after entering R

```
library(devtools)
install_github("whcsu/JMcmprsk")
require(JMcmprsk)
set.seed(123)
yfn=tempfile(pattern = "", fileext = ".txt")
cfn=tempfile(pattern = "", fileext = ".txt")
mfn=tempfile(pattern = "", fileext = ".txt")
k_val=30;p1_val=4;p1a_val=1; p2_val=2;g_val=2;
truebeta=c(10,-1,1.5,0.6);truegamma=c(0.8,-1,0.5,-1); randeffect=c(5,0.5,0.5,0.5);
SimDataC(k_val, p1_val, p1a_val, p2_val, g_val,truebeta, 
         truegamma, randeffect, yfn,  cfn,  mfn)
```

Here is the partial ouput:

```
==20602== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==20602==    at 0x571B989: __printf_fp (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==20602==    by 0x571577F: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==20602==    by 0x571EFC7: fprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==20602==    by 0x4066543: ??? (in /u/home/w/wanghong/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/JMcmprsk/libs/JMcmprsk.so)
==20602==    by 0x4062A40: ??? (in /u/home/w/wanghong/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/JMcmprsk/libs/JMcmprsk.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F21B3D: R_doDotCall (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F220AC: do_dotcall (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F73AC4: Rf_eval (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F759C8: do_begin (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F7389F: Rf_eval (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F79746: R_execClosure (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F73665: Rf_eval (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==20602==
==20602== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20602==    at 0x571B9A8: __printf_fp (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==20602==    by 0x571577F: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==20602==    by 0x571EFC7: fprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==20602==    by 0x4066543: ??? (in /u/home/w/wanghong/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/JMcmprsk/libs/JMcmprsk.so)
==20602==    by 0x4062A40: ??? (in /u/home/w/wanghong/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/JMcmprsk/libs/JMcmprsk.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F21B3D: R_doDotCall (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F220AC: do_dotcall (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F73AC4: Rf_eval (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F759C8: do_begin (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F7389F: Rf_eval (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F79746: R_execClosure (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==20602==    by 0x4F73665: Rf_eval (in /u/local/apps/R/3.4.0/gcc-4.9.3_MKL-2017.0/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
```

I have seen a lot of

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
Use of uninitialised value of size 8
```

What does this mean?

Here is the CPP code for the function SimDataC in question in the (SimDataC.cpp file):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace Rcpp;
static void MulM(const gsl_matrix *XX, const gsl_vector *X, gsl_vector *beta) /******** ####### MulM function ############# ********/
{
    int p = XX->size1;
    int q = XX->size2;

    int i=0,j=0;
    double temp;

    for(i=0;i<p;i++)
    {
        temp=0;
        for(j=0;j<q;j++)  temp+=gsl_matrix_get(XX,i,j)*gsl_vector_get(X,j);
        gsl_vector_set(beta,i,temp);
    }

}

static int GetN(double t)   /******** ####### GetN function ############# ********/
{

    return (int)(t/0.5+1);

}

static double Min(const double t1, const double t2)  /******** ####### Min function ############# ********/
{
    if(t1<t2) return t1;
    else return t2;
}

//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List  SimDataC(SEXP k_val,SEXP p1_val,SEXP p1a_val,SEXP p2_val, SEXP g_val, SEXP truebeta, SEXP truegamma,SEXP randeffect, SEXP yfn, SEXP cfn, SEXP mfn)
{   

  size_t k=1;k=as<int> (k_val);
  size_t p1=1;p1=as<int> (p1_val);
  size_t p1a=1; p1a=as<int> (p1a_val);
  size_t p2=1;p2=as<int> (p2_val);
  size_t g=1;g=as<int> (g_val);

  size_t n=0,n1=0,array_size=k*20;
  size_t i=0,j=0;

  std::string yfile=as<std::string>(yfn);
  std::string cfile=as<std::string>(cfn);
  std::string mfile=as<std::string>(mfn);
  const std::vector <double> tbeta_val=as<std::vector<double> >(truebeta);
  const std::vector <double> tgamma_val=as<std::vector<double> >(truegamma);
  const std::vector <double> reffect_val=as<std::vector<double> >(randeffect);

  if (tbeta_val.size() != p1)
    {
        Rprintf("Error in parameter p1 or truebeta.\n");
      return R_NilValue;      
    }
   if (tgamma_val.size() != p2*2)
    {
        Rprintf("Error in parameter p2 (for two competing risks) or truegamma.\n");
      return R_NilValue;      
    }
  //  int k=500,n,n1,p1=4,p2=2,g=2,p1a=1,,i,j;  /** ######## p1a = 1, array_size=k*20 ######  ****/

    /* allocate space for data */
    gsl_matrix *C = gsl_matrix_alloc(k,p2+2);
    gsl_matrix *FY= gsl_matrix_alloc(array_size, p1+1);          /* initially assign a size for Y, call it fake Y ****/
    gsl_vector *M1= gsl_vector_alloc(k);
    gsl_matrix_set_zero(FY);


    gsl_matrix *VC= gsl_matrix_alloc(p1a+1,p1a+1);
    gsl_vector *RA= gsl_vector_alloc(p1a+1);
    gsl_vector *RI= gsl_vector_alloc(p1a+1);
    gsl_vector *S=gsl_vector_alloc(p1a+1);
    gsl_matrix *V=gsl_matrix_alloc(p1a+1,p1a+1);
    gsl_vector *W=gsl_vector_alloc(p1a+1);

    /* allocate space for true parameters */
    gsl_vector *tbeta = gsl_vector_alloc(p1),
               *tvee = gsl_vector_alloc(g-1);
    gsl_matrix *tgamma = gsl_matrix_alloc(g,p2);



    /* assign the true value to parameters */

    double tsigma=reffect_val[0];
    double tsigmab0=reffect_val[1];
    double tsigmau=reffect_val[3];
    double  rho=0.9, sigmax=1.0, prob=0.5;
      gsl_vector_set(tvee,0,reffect_val[2]);

    double tsigmab0u=sqrt(tsigmab0*tsigmau)*rho;

  for (size_t i=0;i<tbeta_val.size();i++) 
           gsl_vector_set(tbeta,i,tbeta_val[i]);

  for (size_t i=0;i<g;i++)
        {   for(size_t j=0;j<p2;j++)
                {
       gsl_matrix_set(tgamma,i,j,tgamma_val[(i)*(p2)+j]);
                }
       }
  //  gsl_matrix_set(tgamma,0,0,0.8);
  //  gsl_matrix_set(tgamma,0,1,-1);
  //  gsl_matrix_set(tgamma,1,0,0.5);
  //  gsl_matrix_set(tgamma,1,1,-1.5);

    gsl_matrix_set(VC,0,0,tsigmab0);
    gsl_matrix_set(VC,1,1,tsigmau);
    gsl_matrix_set(VC,1,0,tsigmab0u); 

    gsl_linalg_SV_decomp(VC,V,S,W);

    gsl_matrix_set_zero(V);
    for(i=0;i<p1a+1;i++) gsl_matrix_set(V,i,i,sqrt(gsl_vector_get(S,i)));


    double lamda01=0.1, lamda02=0.15;                          /* baseline hazard; constant over time */
    double temp=0.0,x1=0.0,x2=0.0,t1=0.0,t2=0.0,censor=0.0,u=0.0,b0=0.0,error=0.0;
    const gsl_rng_type * T;
    gsl_rng * r;
    gsl_rng_env_setup();
    T = gsl_rng_default;
    r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);

    int point_loc=0;
    double crate=0,rate1=0,rate2=0,max_censor=5;




    for(j=0;j<k;j++)
    {

        for(i=0;i<p1a+1;i++)    gsl_vector_set(RI,i,gsl_ran_gaussian(r,1));
        MulM(V,RI,RA);
        MulM(VC,RA,RI);

        b0=gsl_vector_get(RI,0);
        u=gsl_vector_get(RI,1);      

        x1=gsl_ran_gaussian(r,sqrt(sigmax))+2;
        x2=gsl_ran_bernoulli(r,prob);
        censor=gsl_ran_exponential(r, 25);

        gsl_matrix_set(C,j,2,x1);
        gsl_matrix_set(C,j,3,x2);

        temp=gsl_matrix_get(tgamma,0,0)*x1+gsl_matrix_get(tgamma,0,1)*x2;
        temp=exp(temp+u);
        temp=lamda01*temp;
        t1=gsl_ran_exponential(r, 1/temp);

        temp=gsl_matrix_get(tgamma,1,0)*x1+gsl_matrix_get(tgamma,1,1)*x2;
        temp=exp(temp+gsl_vector_get(tvee,0)*u);
        temp=lamda02*temp;
        t2=gsl_ran_exponential(r, 1/temp);


        if(t1<=t2 && t1<=censor && t1<=max_censor)
        {
            rate1+=1;
            gsl_matrix_set(C,j,0,t1);
            gsl_matrix_set(C,j,1,1);
            n=GetN(t1);               
        }

        if(t2<=t1 && t2<=censor && t2<=max_censor)
        {
            rate2+=1;
            gsl_matrix_set(C,j,0,t2);
            gsl_matrix_set(C,j,1,2);
            n=GetN(t2);               
        }

        if(Min(censor, max_censor)<=t1 && Min(censor, max_censor)<=t2)
        {
            crate+=1;
            gsl_matrix_set(C,j,0,Min(max_censor,censor));
            gsl_matrix_set(C,j,1,0);
            n=GetN(Min(max_censor,censor));
        }  


        for(i=point_loc;i<point_loc+n;i++)
        {
            gsl_matrix_set(FY,i,1,1.0);
            gsl_matrix_set(FY,i,2,(double)(i-point_loc)*0.5);
            gsl_matrix_set(FY,i,3,x2);
            gsl_matrix_set(FY,i,4,(double)(i-point_loc)*0.5*x2);


            error=gsl_ran_gaussian(r,sqrt(tsigma));

            temp=gsl_vector_get(tbeta,0)+gsl_vector_get(tbeta,1)*gsl_matrix_get(FY,i,2)+gsl_vector_get(tbeta,2)*x2
                 +gsl_vector_get(tbeta,3)*x2*gsl_matrix_get(FY,i,2);
            temp=temp+error+b0*gsl_matrix_get(FY,i,2);
            gsl_matrix_set(FY,i,0,temp);
        }

        point_loc+=n;
        gsl_vector_set(M1,j,(double)n);

    }

    n1 = point_loc;
    gsl_matrix *Y = gsl_matrix_alloc(n1,p1+p1a+1);      /* #### now Y's dimension is consistent with the jmc function input format ####### **/

    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)                                   /* #### this part is newly added to make Y in the correct format ####### **/
    {
        gsl_matrix_set(Y,i,0,gsl_matrix_get(FY,i,0));
        gsl_matrix_set(Y,i,1,gsl_matrix_get(FY,i,2));
        for(j=0;j<p1;j++)  gsl_matrix_set(Y,i,j+2,gsl_matrix_get(FY,i,j+1));
    }





    /***** ###### output data ############## *******/

  //write Y file

  FILE *output_F; 

  output_F=fopen(yfile.c_str(),"w");
  if (output_F == NULL)
  {Rprintf("Can't write y file\n");
  }
  fprintf(output_F,"%s   ", "response time_RE intercept time x1 x2\n");


    for(i=0;i<Y->size1;i++)
    {   
        for(j=0;j<Y->size2;j++)   fprintf(output_F,"%f   ", gsl_matrix_get(Y,i,j)); 
        if(i!=Y->size1-1)  fprintf(output_F,"\n");                      
    }
 //close writing files  
  fclose(output_F);

  //write C file

  output_F=fopen(cfile.c_str(),"w");
  if (output_F == NULL)
  {Rprintf("Can't write C file\n");
    //return R_NilValue;
  }
    fprintf(output_F,"%s   ", "surv failure_type   x1         x2\n");

    for(i=0;i<C->size1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<C->size2;j++)   fprintf(output_F,"%f   ", gsl_matrix_get(C,i,j)); 
        if(i!=C->size1-1)  fprintf(output_F,"\n");                      
    }
  //close writing files  
  fclose(output_F);

  //write M file

  output_F=fopen(mfile.c_str(),"w");
  if (output_F == NULL)
  {Rprintf("Can't write M file\n");
    // return R_NilValue;
  }

 for(i=0;i<M1->size;i++)
    {
        fprintf(output_F,"%f", gsl_vector_get(M1,i)); 
        if(i!=M1->size-1)  fprintf(output_F,"\n");                      
    }

   fclose(output_F);


    gsl_matrix_free(C);
    gsl_matrix_free(FY);          
    gsl_vector_free(M1);

    gsl_matrix_free(VC);
    gsl_vector_free(RA);
    gsl_vector_free(RI);
    gsl_vector_free(S);
    gsl_matrix_free(V);
    gsl_vector_free(W);

    gsl_vector_free(tbeta);
    gsl_vector_free(tvee);
    gsl_matrix_free(tgamma);


  Rcpp::List ret;
  ret["censoring_rate"] = crate/(double)k;
  ret["rate1"] = rate1/(double)k;
  ret["rate2"] = rate2/(double)k;   
  ret["yfn"] = yfile.c_str(); 
  ret["cfn"] = cfile.c_str(); 
  ret["mfn"] = mfile.c_str(); 

  return ret;

}
```

Can anyone tell me what to do or where to start?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

valgrind error messages are explained in the user manual.
E.g. you might refer to :

https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.uninitvals

But the other sections are also useful.  For example, if you read the section that explains the memcheck command line options, you will find some options that will (at the price of an even slower execution) indicate the origin of the uninitialized value.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will have a try.